# Error `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor` is deprecated in SQL statement interceptor class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I did the migration to spring boot 3 and my SQL statement interceptor gives an error: `'org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor' is deprecated.` I don't how to resolve it.

Here's my code:

```
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

public class Interceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(sql) && sql.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
            final String entityName = sql.substring(7, sql.indexOf("."));
            final String idEntreprise = MDC.get("idEntreprise");

            if (StringUtils.hasLength(entityName)
                    && !entityName.toLowerCase().contains("entreprise")
                    && !entityName.toLowerCase().contains("roles")
                    && StringUtils.hasLength(idEntreprise)) {

                if (sql.contains("where")) {
                    sql = sql + " and "+entityName+".idEntreprise = "+idEntreprise;
                } else {
                    sql = sql + " where "+entityName+".idEntreprise = "+idEntreprise;
                }

      }
            }
            return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
        }
    }
```

In my code I replace `EmptyInterceptor` with `Interceptor` class, but nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Try to implement StatementInspector and override inspect(String sql) method

```
public class Interceptor implements StatementInspector {
 //Use this method instead of onPrepareStatement
    @Override
    public String inspect(String sql) {
        ...
    }
}
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/jdbc/spi/StatementInspector.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).